# how to access individual data in for loop in django template

Tags: django, loops

```
{
 a {
      0 {
         item:1,
         item2:1
        },
      1 {
         item:1,
         item2:1
        },
      2 {
         item3:1,
         item5:1
        },
      3 {
         ite6:1,
         item7:1
        }
   }
}
```

Now I wanna display all (item, item2) from 0,1,2,3 in a for loop. for display in a table. how to access individually.

Comment: Add your view and what you have tried so far in your template

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for a,b in dict.items %}
    {% for c,d in b.items %}
        {% for e,f in d.items %}
        {# here e is your keys(0,1,2,3), and f.keys are your tuples (item, item2)  #}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```